# How do i "disable" or recalculate modifiers?

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier, surface-deform

I have a cube with an array modify, and a surfacedeform targeting a plane. The plane has a curve modifier targeting to a circle. (this is a simplified version of my issue).

When I change the size of the array, the surfacedeform breaks, so I try to rebind. However, because the plane has a curve modifier, it cant bind. Is there some way to do this without completely removing the curve modifier (hiding doesnt help)?

Comment: You can try using a linked duplicate (ALT D) without any modifier and set this as the target of the surface deform. Parent it to the base object so they move and transform together

Comment: @Gorgious that works great, thanks! so i create a linked duplicate of the plane remove the modifiers, bind the array to that, then i just change the target and it applies as expected! fantastic!